# ObservableBuffer giving IndexOutOfBounds in Scala

Tags: scala, buffer

I am mesmerized. The below code is giving me an indexoutofbound error. But if I were to delete the slashes enabling `for(j <- i until tmpArray.length)` it would work. I really do not understand why it is happening, and would appreciate an explanation.

```
 for(i <- 0 until tmpArray.length)
{
 // for(j <- i until tmpArray.length)
 // {
    if( date.getValue != null && tmpArray(i).date != date.getValue )
    {
      tmpArray.remove(i)
    }
//  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you try `ArrayBuffer` instead of `ObservableBuffer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the array as you "iterate" over it.

You are actually iterating over the range `0 until tmpArray.length`, which is calculated up front. At some point, you reduce the length of the array (or, I assume so, as I can't find `remove` on the `Array` class). But it's still going to continue the iteration up to whatever the last index was when you created the range.

When you uncomment the inner `for` block, you're making it recompute the range for each step of the outer `for`. And it just so happens that the `j` range will simply have nothing in it if `i >= tmpArray.length`. So it inadvertently guards against that failure.

This is very C-style (imperative) code. It looks like all you're trying to do is remove some items from an array. That's what `filter` is for.

```
val result = tmpArray.filter { d =>
  if(date.getValue != null && d != date.getValue) false else true
}
```

This creates a *new* array (`result`) by passing an anonymous function to `tmpArray.filter`. It will pass each item in the array to your "predicate", and if it returns `true`, it'll keep that item in `result`, otherwise it will omit it.

You should note that I avoided saying "loop". Scala's `for` isn't for making loops. It's actually syntax sugar for calling methods like `foreach` and `map`. Google "scala for comprehensions" for more detail.

If you insist on creating a C-style loop using indexes and a loop variable, you'll want to use `while`, so that you can check if `i < tmpArray.length` each time.

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot. I am used to C, I started with Scala last month.